# Using \thetitle in the header line (fancyhdr)? Outside the title page \thetitle showing up as "0"? If I remove \tableofcontents it works?

Tags: table-of-contents, titles

I'd like to be able to print my \thetitle in the `fancyheader` so that if I change my title, it automatically changes the header too.

Getting my MWE ready for this post, I noticed that if I get rid of my `\tableofcontents` it suddenly works. But since I need that in my real document, I'm not sure what to do?

I've also noticed that I use both `titlesec` and `titling`. Is that OK, or is that breaking things?

In my real document I also haven an abstract after my title page, which also seems to interrupt the "title-making", so that after that the `\thetitle` also doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Thanks :)

```
% Options for packages loaded elsewhere
\PassOptionsToPackage{unicode}{hyperref}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
%
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, margin=1in]{geometry}



\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{titling}
\author{ReaderGuy42}
\title{An interesting title}


% HEADINGS & SECTIONS%
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{color}
%\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}
\definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.75}

\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\filleft\Huge\bfseries}{\thesection\hsp\textcolor{gray75}{|}\hsp}{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries}

\AddToHook{cmd/section/before}{\clearpage\setcounter{footnote}{0} }





%% FANCY HEADER %%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf[]{}
\fancyhead[R]{ReaderGuy \thepage}
\fancyhead[C]{Proposal}

\fancyhead[L]{Working Title: \emph{\thetitle}}

\fancyfoot[]{}
\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, margin=1in]{geometry}
\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont
\usepackage{setspace}
%\doublespacing
\newlength\FHoffset
\setlength\FHoffset{1cm}
\fancyheadoffset{\FHoffset}




\AtBeginEnvironment{quote}{\par\singlespacing\small}


\setlength{\parindent}{5em}



% START DOCUMENT %
\makeatletter

\begin{document}
\setlength{\footnotesep}{2mm} % shrinks gap between footnotes

\pagenumbering{roman}
\begin{titlepage}



\begin{center}
    \vfill
    {\large \scshape School”}\\[1.4cm]
    {\Large Essay}\\[0.5cm]
    \rule{\textwidth}{1.5pt}\\[0cm]
    {\huge \bfseries \thetitle \par  \Large A subtitle\ }\\[-0.5cm]
    \rule{\textwidth}{1.5pt}\\[2.5cm]
  {\Large by}\\[1cm]
 {\huge \bfseries\theauthor}\\
    \vfill
    \vspace{1cm}
\end{center}

\end{titlepage}
\pagenumbering{roman}


\tableofcontents                 <------------------ the problem!!!?

\newpage



% START BODY %

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\begin{spacing}{2}

$body$ 

 \thetitle

\end{spacing}


\clearpage


\end{document}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `titling` and `titlesec` packages fight against each other, because both define `\thetitle`.

Save the `titling` meaning in a different command.

The code below reorganizes your preamble with package loading first and settings later. This avoids the unnecessary and potential harmful duplications you had.

I changed a bit the title page part so the spacing is better.

I also removed some *harmful* parts, namely

- `\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont`
- `\makeatletter`

and showed a better way to reset the `footnote` counter at each section.

```
% Options for packages loaded elsewhere
\PassOptionsToPackage{unicode}{hyperref}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
%

\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, margin=1in,headheight=14.5pt]{geometry}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}


\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}
\definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.75}

\titleformat{\section}[hang]
  {\filleft\Huge\bfseries}
  {\thesection\hsp\textcolor{gray75}{|}\hsp}
  {0pt}
  {\Huge\bfseries}
\AddToHook{cmd/section/before}{\clearpage\setcounter{footnote}{0}}

%% FANCY HEADER %%
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf[]{}
\fancyhead[R]{ReaderGuy \thepage}
\fancyhead[C]{Proposal}

\fancyhead[L]{Working Title: \emph{\THETITLE}}

\newlength\FHoffset
\setlength\FHoffset{1cm}
\fancyheadoffset{\FHoffset}

\AtBeginEnvironment{quote}{\par\singlespacing\small}


\setlength{\parindent}{5em}
\setlength{\footnotesep}{2mm} % shrinks gap between footnotes

%% metadata
\author{ReaderGuy42}
\title{An interesting title}
\AtBeginDocument{\NewCommandCopy{\THETITLE}{\thetitle}}

% START DOCUMENT %

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\begin{titlepage}



\begin{center}
    \vfill
    {\large \scshape School”}\\[1.4cm]
    {\Large Essay}\\[0.5cm]
    \rule{\textwidth}{1.5pt}\\[0cm]
    {\huge \bfseries \thetitle \par  \Large A subtitle\\}
    \rule{\textwidth}{1.5pt}\\[2.5cm]
  {\Large by}\\[1cm]
 {\huge \bfseries\theauthor}\\
    \vfill
    \vspace{1cm}
\end{center}

\end{titlepage}

\pagenumbering{roman}


\tableofcontents

\newpage



% START BODY %

\pagenumbering{arabic}

$body$ 

 \thetitle

\clearpage

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect!